# What would be the best way to have a different navbar for my home page than the rest of the site in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two nav bars, one for the home page, and one for the rest of the site. I'm not sure how to go about doing this in a good DRY way. It seems like i want to put the rest of the sites navbars in the layouts views, but I don't know how to exclude a layout from a page I guess? The rest of the home page layout is the same as the rest of the site, so the only thing I would want to exclude is the nav bar for that page and replace it with another. The links will also be the same. So navigation_links can also be rendered in both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem, but the one I like most is taking advantage of Rails' Template Inheritance. Let's say your home controller looks like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
end
```

Rails looks up the layout for the views rendered by this controller by its name, `home`. If there's no such layout, it will look for one named after its super class, `application` and so on. This is [explained in the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#layout-inheritance).

Looking up partials actually works the same way. Let's say you were to render a partial `navigation_bar` in your layout:

```
render 'navigation_bar'
```

If you don't specify its exact location (like `application/navigation_bar`, Rails will again use template inheritance to look for the partial.

So first it will look for `home/navigation_bar`, and then for `application/navigation_bar`. You can use this to your advantage if you only want to display a different navigation bar, without redefining the layout or anything else.

So you need to place your general navigation bar in `application/_navigation_bar`, and your home navigation bar in `home/_navigation_bar`. Then render the navigation bar in your layout:

```
render 'navigation_bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) helper method.

In your view template, perhaps `application.html.erb`, you can do:

```
<% if content_for? :nav %>
  <%= content_for :nav %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your home page:

```
<% content_for :nav, render('layouts/custom_nav') %>
```

Personally, I prefer this method—it's declarative, it lets others (including future you) know explicitly that the default nav can be overridden.